# Create and manage Emulator after update of Android Studio 2.3 on March 2017

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Does anybody know how to create and manage emulator after the latest update of Android Studio 2.3 on March 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try in the action action bar :

**Tools** -> **Android** -> **AVD Manager**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This option is no more available.

Comment: I have Android studio 2.3 and this option is still present.

Comment: May be there is something wrong with my project, since i installed the new update, i don't see AVD manager button anymore. the options that i have under Tools menu are : Tasks & contexts, Generate Java Docs, New Scratch file, IDE Scripting console, Create command line launcher.

Comment: Chek if the android sdk location is set

Answer (score 0):

This is what the new Tools menu look like

[New Tools menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMzz7.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is a (very small) button on the icon bar

[image: Android studio - AVD Manager icon]